# Is there any way to delete a record from a table which are in relationship?

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I have created a main table as follows

```
public class main()
{
@Id
private String ID;

 @OneToMany(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
 @JoinColumn(name="ID")
   private List<Subtable1> Subtab;


@OneToMany(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
@JoinColumn(name="ID")
 private List<Subtable2> Stutab2;

getter n setter...
}
```

my sub classes are

```
public class subtable1{
@Column(name="Name")
String name; 

 @ManyToOne
 @JoinColumn(name="ID")
 private main m;
getter n setter..
}

public class subtable2{
@Column(name="AGE")
String age; 

 @ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="ID")
private main m;
getter n setter...
}
```

Now i need to delete a record in main table. Its not allowing me to delete it directly in the main table.If I delete record from subtable1 and subtable2,it is allowing me to delete the corresponding record in main table.This process is too long so I need to delete a record in main table and its corresponding records should be deleted in sub-tables.How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

it is possible by design of tables in mysql. CASCADE is what you need:
take a look at this:

> **CASCADE** will propagate the change when the parent changes. (If you
>   delete a row, rows in constrained tables that reference that row will
>   also be deleted, etc.)
>
> **SET NULL** sets the column value to NULL when a parent row goes away.
>
> **RESTRICT** causes the attempted DELETE of a parent row to fail.